# Java Recursive Function: Only add elements with specific attribute

Tags: java, function, recursion, attributes

I am working on a project for my thesis. Haven't really done much coding before and would appreciate some help with the following problem I am trying to solve:

Initially I created a list of products. Every product p has some attributes, one of them a boolean called `isCool`. I want to get all permutations of that list with Products. So I created a recursive function that returns all permutations of p. So if I have 3 Products I will get 3! = 6 lists, because there are 6 possible permutations.

Now I want the recursive function to only accept products, where the attribute `isCool == false`.
How do I do that? The code is attached.
Can anyone help?

```
public class PermutateArray {

    public List<List<Product>> permute (Product[] p) {
        List<List<Product>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        permuteHelper(list, new ArrayList<>(), p);
        return list;
    }

    private void permuteHelper(List<List<Product>> list, List<Product> resultList, Product[] p) {

        // Base case
        if (resultList.size() == p.length) {
            // list.add(new ArrayList<>(resultList));

            //Startknoten ans Ende anfügen
            List<Product> target = new ArrayList<>(resultList);
            target.add(resultList.get(0));
            list.add(target);   

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {

                if (resultList.contains(p[i])) {
                    continue;
                }
                    resultList.add(p[i]);   
                    permuteHelper(list, resultList, p);         
                    resultList.remove(resultList.size() - 1);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if (resultList.contains(p[i]) || !p[i].isCool()) {
                    continue;
}

Comment: So you want to filter `Product[] p` based on `isCool` attribute before calculating the possible permutations?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: So it's easy stuff right? `permute` method seems a good place to write some filtering logic before the recursive function invocation. There's a lot of existing examples on how to filter an array in Java. I'll not give you a ready to use code cause there's multiple ways to achieve that (using streams, loop approaches, etc.).